# disc usage and file system

Tags: filesystem, disk-usage

How can the root directory be at 100 percent disc usage while its subdirectories not be? Is space allocated on a per directory basis? In the below example, it shows that the root is 100 percent used. Does this mean if I try to add content to one of the nonroot directories, it should work but if I try to add to the root, it won't work? I was expecting that 100 percent usage would be the total of ALL the directories added up, but as the example below shows, that's not the case:

```
$ df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/eubuntu10x32-root
                      3.5G  3.3G     0 100% /
none                  1.5G  180K  1.5G   1% /dev
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /dev/shm
none                  1.5G   40K  1.5G   1% /var/run
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /var/lock
none                  1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /lib/init/rw
none                  3.5G  3.3G     0 100% /var/lib/ureadahead/debugfs
/dev/sdb               50G   27G   21G  57% /home
/dev/sda1             228M   35M  181M  17% /boot
```

Thanks for some explanation of disc usage on filesystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### File systems and mount points

You're missing out on a very important way Ubuntu/Linux handles file systems: all comes down to the same root (`/`) and other file systems ("volumes", "disks", "partitions") will be *mounted* on a location *inside* the root.

To explain two most interesting lines:

- Your `/` *is* full:

  ```
  /dev/mapper/eubuntu10x32-root   3.5G  3.3G     0 100% /
  ```

  Here you see a "device mapper" meta-device being used for your root filesystem. I think you're using LVM here or encryption.

  3.5GiB for a `/` is a very low capacity for a desktop installation, unless you have directories like `/usr`, `/var` moved out of it. In your case it's clearly not sufficient.
- Your second disk (`sdb`, without partitions) is mounted at `/home` and a partition of `sda` is mounted as `/boot`:

  ```
  /dev/sdb               50G   27G   21G  57% /home
  /dev/sda1             228M   35M  181M  17% /boot
  ```

  This separated `/boot` is common for a LVM/encrypted installation to allow the bootloader (Grub) to load the relevant software/drivers to be able to reach your other file systems to actually boot the operating system.

So, basically, your `/home` and `/boot` aren't just directories. They are directories on the `/` file system, but there's another file system mounted *on top* of it. This means that whenever you descend into it, you're looking into a different file system. Each file system has its own capacity, listed by `df`.

While you moved out `/home` and `/boot`, this wasn't enough to have sufficient space available on `/`. Solutions: grow the `/` file system, move out more like `/usr` or `/var` to another file system.

#### Are all directories under `/` mount points?

Directories not being a mount point are actual regular directories part of file system in mounted as `/`. There are also special ones, which don't actually represent data on disks, but in UNIX/Linux, *everything is represented as files* such as sockets, kernel interfaces (`/proc`, `/sys`), etc. and even directories itself are files.

#### How does this compare to Windows?

Windows tends to hide the difference between the devices/partitions and the actual file system being mounted. This means that a `C:` "drive" can also be mounted as such. In Ubuntu/Linux, you'll see that a partition, e.g. `/dev/sda1` (first partition on `sda`) can be *mounted* (content being made available to the user) to *any* location. There's no second root for this like Windows makes the second drive a `D:`.

Answer (score 0):

As `df` shows, `/dev/mapper/eubuntu10x32-root` is mounted on `/` (the root of your file system).

The other "folders" that `df` shows are not really folders but also what is called "mount point".

For instance,

- the *real* partition `/dev/mapper/eubuntu10x32-root` mounted on `/` is full.
- the *real* partition `/dev/sdb` mounted on `/home` is not full (57%).

**The thing is that you can't access these disk partitions directly**. So partitions have to be mounted on some mount points (folders). For example, the `/home` folder is called a mount point for `/dev/sdb` since the physical disk is "linked" to this folder.

This means that when you write something into `/home`, your data are actually written to `/dev/sdb`, **not** `/dev/mapper/eubuntu10x32-root`. 3.5G is small for a root partition and you lack space on it but you can still write in your home directory because there are 21G available in it.

Answer (score 0):

Linux works a bit differently then windows. You have a "root filesystem", and that is the disk you have mounted (pointed towards) the directory called `/`. But other discs, like for instance your your `/home` disc can be there. Where in windows they would be for instance `c:\` and `d:\` , you end up with them in "subdirectories" in linux, called "mountpoints".

So while the disc that you use as `/` might be full, if you mount an empty terabyte disc as `/home` it will be that: empty.

This also means that if you have enough space on `/home` you cannot add a file to `/otherdir`: that gets added to an actual subdir on the `/` partition!